# What to release

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I do have a problem with understanding memory management, although I thought I got it. After I imported my data from a plist I got totally messed with my understanding of reference counting (and spend a whole day trying to fix it)

My plist's structure is basically just:

```
<dict>
<key>Menue1</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>pic1</key>
        <string>a</string>
        ...and so on...
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>pic1</key>
        <string>a</string>
        ...and so on...
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>pic1</key>
        <string>a</string>
        ...and so on...
    </dict>
</array>
<key>Menue2</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>pic1</key>
        <string>a</string>
        ...and so on...
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>pic</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>text</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

And in the code I access this content via

```
//to get the path
path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistsName" ofType:@"plist"]; 

//to get the root dictionary from path      
NSDictionary *tempdict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
    dict = tempdict;
// [tempdict release]; <-- app crashes when I release this

// to get the Array of dicts inside of the dict "Menue1"
exercises = [dict objectForKey:@"Menue1"]; 

// to get the dictionary containing the detailed informations
exerciseViewContent = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[exercises objectAtIndex:0]];
```

I do understand the idea of reference counting (I think so), but I apparently fail basic maths.

Due to the `@interface` I suppose the references been as followed:

```
dict = 1
exercises = 1
exerciseViewContent = 1
```

After `viewDidLoad`, where I do all this stuff above i assume it to be like

```
dict = 1
exercises = 1
exerciseViewContent = 2
tempdict = 1
```

So at FIRST I thought I'd have to release `exerciseViewContent` once inside `viewDidLoad`, as well as `tempdict`, and release all three (`dict, exercise, exerciseViewContent`) in the `dealloc` to get all of them to equal 0. After fiddling quite a while I found out that I have to release `exerciseViewContent` in `dealloc`, but not `exercise` or `dict` (i do set their properties as retained in the interface and synthesize them though), but to not need to release `tempdict` totally is more than I understand, as I definitely used alloc with it. Just by fiddling it works now (till now).

So I'd like to know:

- First of all: is my memory management correct like this?
- When is e.g. `dict` released, as I never release it (or my App crashes)?
- Is this the proper way of accessing dicts and arrays from a plist?
- I assume `initWithContentsOfFile` includes autorelease, but how should I know that? Is there a list of methods that include autorelease (or a list that doesn't, what ever would be shorter)?
- I'd like to have a rule of thumb that actually works out, because "every alloc or init needs a release" apparently doesn't fit here.

Further, do I need to release "path"?

And also is:

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

the same as a release, as I apparently also don't have to release timer (`NSTimer`), although I set it's property to retain? Or is this because it's a `NSTimer` which doesn't need to be released, just like `NSInteger`? And where in the class reference can I see which type has to be released and which hasn't by default?

And:

- (from the Xcode Template:)

  ```
  (void)viewDidUnload {
      [super viewDidUnload];
      // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
      // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
  }
  ```

Will I still have to release "myOutlet" if I set it's property to retain in the interface?

Comment: How do you implement/synthesize the setter for dict, excercises and exerciseViewContent?

Comment: "... `exercise` or `dict` (i do set their properties as retained in the interface and synthesize them though)". Note that `self.dict = tempDict;` and `dict = tempDict;` are **not** the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables dict and tempDict are pointers to objects, not the object(s) themselves.  So when you do this:

```
dict = tempDict;
```

you have really only set an alias to the *same* object.  Sending release to tempDict is also sending it to dict.  This is why you get the crash.  You have released an object you only just allocated and therefore you no longer own it.  The object is deallocated leaving dict a dangling pointer.

> is my memory management correct like this?

Without the `[tempDict release]`, up to a point yes.  When you are done with them, you need to release both dict and exerciseViewContent because you obtained them with an alloc.

> When is e.g. dict released, as I never release it (or my App crashes)?

As I said above, tempDict points to the same object.  Release tempDict and you release dict.

> Is this the proper way of accessing dicts and arrays from a plist?

It's OK except I would just obtain exerciseViewContent like this:

```
exerciseViewContent = [exercises objectAtIndex:0];
```

then you don't need to release it.

> assume initWithContentsOfFile includes autorelease, but how should I know that?

No, it doesn't.  The important point is that the object was obtained with alloc which means you own it.  How you should know it is by understanding the C[ocoa Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

> I'd like to have a rule of thumb that actually works out, because "every alloc <s>or init</s> needs a release" apparently doesn't fit here.

Yes, it does fit.  You were just misunderstanding the meaning of the line:

```
dict = tempDict;
```

Comment: @Praveen: I've had lots of practice :)

Comment: me-->*facepalm* Okay, that was quite stupid of me.. Thanks for that really helpful answer!