# Re-using local variables and implications on memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Out of  convenience often when I have a method where I need
to reuse the same local variable for different purposes I tend do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", nil];
[self fooWithArray:mutArray];

mutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"three", @"four", nil];
[self barWithArray:mutArray];

//and

MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc]initWithString:@"one"];
self.oneClass = myClass;
[myClass release];

myClass = [[MyClass alloc]initWithString:@"two"];
self.twoClass = myClass;
[myClass release];
```

Memory-wise, is this the right thing to do  ?
Is this code prone to memory leaks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to assign objects to variables before using them. The only reason I can see for doing that would be verbosity, but it's not required.

You could get away with:

```
[self fooWithArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", nil]];
[self barWithArray:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"three", @"four", nil]];

//and

self.oneClass = [[[MyClass alloc]initWithString:@"one"] autorelease];
self.twoClass = [[[MyClass alloc]initWithString:@"two"] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", nil];
[self fooWithArray:mutArray];
```

The first statement returns an auto released object and hence you not releasing them will not cause any memory leak. An attempt to release will actually crash the application.

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyCalss alloc]initWithString:@"one"];
self.oneClass = myClass;
[myClass release]
```

Assuming that you have oneClass declared with a retain property, the second line increases the reference count to 2. Now when you release myClass as you are doing in the third line care must be taken to release oneClass in your methods dealloc as the reference count is still 1 after the `[myClass release]`.

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124564/what-to-release-crash-and-or-leak/6124761#6124761) in which he neatly describes memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Great question.
So far as memory is concerned there wont be any issue because you as releasing the allocated memory. But I am afraid, it is not a good practice.
What you are doing is something like this :

```
MyClass *myClass;   // in .h
```

because you are using the same object twice.